# cant plot seaborn graphs side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, seaborn

I have done research here in SO and all the answers that i have found do not solve my issue.
I have 4 histograms that i want to plot over 2 rows and 2 columns.

If i just want to plot 2 histograms over 1 row then it works fine but the moment i add more histograms then the whole thing dies!
this is the code:

```
`fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
sns.distplot(iot['opex_euro'],ax=ax1)
sns.distplot(iot['cost_of_delay'],ax=ax2)
sns.distplot(iot['customer_commitment_value'],ax=ax3)
sns.distplot(iot['ktlo_value'],ax=ax4)
plt.show()`
```

and this is the error message that i get:

```
`ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-5b6d5d693b20> in <module>()
1 #plotParams()
2 
----> 3 fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
4 sns.distplot(iot['opex_euro'],ax=ax1)
5 sns.distplot(iot['cost_of_delay'],ax=ax2)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`
```

can i please get steered in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For subplot figures with `m` rows and `n` columns, where `m` > 1 and `n` > 1, [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) returns a 2D array of `Axes` with shape `m` x `n`. This is done so that it's easier to acess a specific axis using row/column indices:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
bottom_right_ax = axes[1, 1]
```

Since it's a 2D array of `Axes`, you'll need a slightly different unpacking syntax for your code to work:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

In the line above, the tuple `(ax1, ax2)` unpacks to the first (top) row of the 2D `Axes` array, and the tuple `(ax3, ax4)` does the same for the last (bottom) row.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: Here I am first defining how many subplots I want to make using plt.subplots(nrows, ncols). Also I have put sharex=True, which means you will share x axis. If you want to have separate x axis for all 4 subplots then make it sharex=False (default)

Here I used randomly generated data to generate the plot, you can use your own data.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 7), sharex=True)

sns.despine(left=True)

# Plot a simple distribution of the desired columns
sns.distplot(df['col1'], color="b", ax=axes[0, 0])
sns.distplot(df['col2'], color="m", ax=axes[0, 1])
sns.distplot(df['col3'], color="r", ax=axes[1, 0])
sns.distplot(df['col4'], color="g", ax=axes[1, 1])

plt.setp(axes, yticks=[])
plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig("sample.png")
```

[image: 4 Subplots with shared x axis]